# magit-status does not highlight diffs

Tags: magit, highlighting

I'm currently seeing a display problem in Magit. For a while I've seen that when I do `magit-status`, the diffs are no longer highlighted. I didn't care for a while, thinking it was the theme I've been using, but today I tried other themes and in all of them there's no highlighting. I installed [`solarized-dark-theme`](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs) which is used in the screenshots shown [here](https://magit.vc/screenshots/), but I don't have the highlighting:

[image]

Is there any setting I need to turn on? When searching I couldn't find any references to a similar problem.

P.S. I'm using: `GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0, NS appkit-1561.20 Version 10.13.3 (Build 17D47)) of 2018-02-08`

and `magit-version` is: `Magit 2.11.0-510-g1c4fa9b1, Git 2.13.6 (Apple Git-96), Emacs 25.3.1, darwin`.

### Update

Thanks @tarsius, now I know this is an issue specific to my configuration and not an issue with magit or the themes themselves, it works just fine when using `magit-emacs-Q-command`. I will try to "bisect" my configuration to find the issue but if someone can easily point what's wrong with my configuration will be helpful. [This is my init.el](https://github.com/ZzAntares/.emacs.d/blob/master/init.el).

### Update #2

Seem's that the conflicting setting is `(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook 'hc-highlight-tabs)`, I use this to see the tab character in files. Is there any workaround to make it co-exist with `magit`?

Thanks!

Comment: Please start by trying to reproduce the issue following the instructions in https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Debugging-Tools.html.

Comment: Thanks it turns out that it works well when only loading magit and the theme, clearly I have a conflicting setting.

Comment: You can try the usual recursive bisection method for debugging: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23772957/3084001.

Comment: `magit-after-revert-hook` and `magit-not-reverted-hook` no longer exist. Also I recommend you use `diff-hl` instead of `git-gutter`.

Comment: Thank you! I found the conflicting setting, is this: `(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook 'hc-highlight-tabs)` which I use to see the tabs on files. Is there a workaround so this config can coexist with magit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magit and Font-Lock are not compatible.

When Magit inserts text into a buffer it takes care of setting the `face` property (and others).

Font-Lock on the other hand takes a buffer that already contains all the text and then determines which parts of the buffer need to be propertized (~= colorized). This does not only set the `face` property (and others) for text that does not have that set yet but for which a rule says that it should, it also *removes* the existing `face` property from text that has it set, if there is no rule that says that that should be so.

As a result Font-Lock removes all the text properties that Magit put in place. Font-Lock is most suitable for buffers that visit files. It is not suitable for packages/modes like Dired, Custom, and Magit.

---

*Something* is enabling Font-Lock in Magit buffers, but it is not `(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook 'hc-highlight-tabs)` alone. That only says to call `hc-highlight-tabs` when `font-lock-mode` is enabled in a buffer anyway. It is however possible that the package that defines `hc-highlight-tabs` (what package is that?), makes the mistake of enabling `font-lock-mode` in Magit buffers.

Something similar happens if you enable `global-whitespace-mode` without setting `whitespace-modes` to exclude the various Magit modes.

---

Magit itself provides some support for highlighting certain whitespace in diffs. These features can be activated in the Custom group `magit-diff`. You probably want `magit-diff-highlight-indentation`.

Comment: Thank you, the package that provides that function is `highlight-chars.el`, I didn't see a way to exclude modes, so I've only enabled it in go-mode which  is one of the main modes where I want this feature.